# Comments closed but enabled on edit screen

Tags: comments

I have been trying different themes, and I just noticed "Comments closed" on every post.  I know that it wasn't always that way, but I went back to the previous theme and then back to one from further back.

- Barista
- Boldly Blue
- 2012

I recently deleted two comments.  Can that close them on all posts?  I verified on two of them that comments should be enabled.  Even though they aren't custom post types, I tried the trick in [Why are the comments disabled by default on my custom_post_types?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/38405/why-are-the-comments-disabled-by-default-on-my-custom-post-types) but no change.  Also looked at [Comments enabled, but disabled at the same time](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/198639/comments-enabled-but-disabled-at-the-same-time) but I'm reluctant to add code just to restore something that shouldn't have gone away.

Comment: It is really tough debugging such issues as it is not related to core itself. You have eliminated themes to be the issue, so I would again go the plugin route. I would however first enable comments again and then take it from there. Also, set debug to true and check for obvious errors

Comment: Comments are still enabled by default and explicitly on the two posts I checked.  I haven't changed plugins in a long time.  Where is the debug flag?

Comment: It is in `wp-config.php`. I usually use a plugin called Debug Objects for debugging purposes, works great

Comment: I'll try it—tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{sheepish grin}

Had nothing to do with plugins.  Was "comments automatically closed after twenty days."